# Gridcontrol edit/update mandatory fields different colour

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, edit, background-color, gridcontrol

I'm just wondering how can I change background colour of mandatory fields while adding new row.
So for example name and surname would be red (mandatory) and phone would be default white.

Thank you
Patryk

Comment: FYI for those seeking to close this question.  I understand why you might, and at first glance I would too.  However, based on the nature of Dev Express tools, this is actually a reasonable question.  If you are conversant with Dev Express and still think it's a bad question, I respect our difference in opinion.  If not, I ask you to consider this before casting your vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is through the grid's designer -- in most cases you don't need to write any code to accomplish this.

If you go to the Grid View designer, select the menu item "Appearance" and "Format Rules:"

[image]

From here, you can add a format condition by clicking the plus icon:

[image]

Under "Column," pick the column you want the format condition to apply to.

Under "Rule," pick an appropriate rule -- based on what you described, you probably want "Format Based on a Value," `FormatConditionRuleValue`.

On the "Rule" tab of this same dialog, you can set your "Value1" and "Condition" properties accordingly, for example Value1 = 15, Condition = "equals."

The "Appearance" property will let you determine how to format the cell based on these conditions.

The beauty of this approach is it's all designer-based code, and it's very easy to customize.  The logic behind the formatting is also very transparent.  The format conditions have been expanded to let you evaluate expressions as well, meaning you can create your own formulas using other column values and functions.

If all else fails, you can use the `RowCellStyle` event, but my first attempt would always to be to use the designer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event gvView_CustomDrawCell and set background color only if the line is in state that you need (Added, Detached ...)

```
 private void gvView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Column != null && (e.Column.Name == bgcName.Name || e.Column.Name == bgcSureName.Name))
      {        
        DataRow focusedRow = gvView.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
        if (focusedRow != null)
        {          
          if (focusedRow.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
          {
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 10, 30, 200);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

asd